# Trouble Connecting Qlik Sense to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, qliksense

I created a free trial account for Qlik Sense, and I'm trying to connect it to a MongoDB database. From the Qlik web console, I'm required to input my MongoDB Server, Port and Database (then a Username and Password and AuthSource). See below.

How do I find this information from my MongoDB console? What is an AuthSource?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`AuthSource` is an optional parameter.

From MongoDB documentation:

> Specify the database name associated with the user's credentials. If authSource is unspecified, authSource defaults to the defaultauthdb specified in the connection string. If defaultauthdb is unspecified, then authSource defaults to admin.

The link to `AuthSource` MongoDB documentation is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.authSource)